# Negroni continues to call other handlers after request is completed

Tags: go, gorilla, negroni

My web-application in Go (using Gorilla `mux` and `negroni`) has about 20 handlers split into three groups based on what Middleware functions should be applied. Specifically:

- Group 1: Static requests (no middleware at all)

  ```
  GET   /favicon.ico
  GET   /files
  GET   /files/index.html
  GET   /files/favicon.ico
  ```
- Group 2: Requests that should have CORS middleware only, no authentication:

  ```
  GET   /
  GET   /login
  POST  /login
  GET   /auth-configuration
  GET   /service-status
  ```
- Group 3: Requests that should have both CORS and authentication middleware applied:

  ```
  GET   /articles
  POST  /articles
  PUT   /articles/etc
  PATCH /articles/etc
  ```

This is my code that sets-up the HTTP server:

```
func run() {

    negroniStack := setUpNegroni()

    bindAddr := // ...

    http.ListenAndServe(bindAddr, negroniStack)
}

func setUpNegroni() negroni.Negroni {

    negroniStack := negroni.Negroni{}

    staticNegroni := setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForStaticRequests()
    loginNegroni  := setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForLogin()
    serviceNegroni = setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForService()

    negroniStack.UseHandler(&staticNegroni)
    negroniStack.UseHandler(&loginNegroni)
    negroniStack.UseHandler(&serviceNegroni)

    return negroniStack
}

func setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForStaticRequests() negroni.Negroni {

    staticNegroni := negroni.Negroni{}
    staticRouter := mux.NewRouter()

    staticRouter.PathPrefix("/files").HandlerFunc(staticHandler)
    staticRouter.Path("/favicon.ico").HandlerFunc(staticHandler)

    staticNegroni.UseHandler(staticRouter)
    return staticNegroni
}

func setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForLogin() negroni.Negroni {

    authNegroni := negroni.Negroni{}

    corsMiddleware := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods:     []string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"},
        AllowCredentials:   true,
        OptionsPassthrough: false,
    })

    authNegroni.Use(corsMiddleware)

    authRouter := mux.NewRouter()

    authRouter.HandleFunc("/login", HandlePostAuth).Methods("POST")
    authRouter.HandleFunc("/login", HandleGetAuth) // GET

    authNegroni.UseHandler(authRouter)

    return authNegroni
}

func setUpRoutesAndMiddlewareForService() negroni.Negroni {

    serviceNegroni := negroni.Negroni{}

    corsMiddleware := cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods:     []string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"},
        AllowCredentials:   true,
        OptionsPassthrough: false,
    })
    serviceNegroni.Use(corsMiddleware)

    serviceNegroni.UseFunc(jwtMiddleware)

    serviceRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    serviceRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", HandleGetArticles).Methods("GET")
    serviceRouter.HandleFunc("/articles", HandlePostArticles).Methods("POST")
    // etc

    serviceNegroni.UseHandler(serviceRouter)

    return serviceNegroni
}
```

I believe this is correct based on the "Route Specific Middleware" section in [Negroni's documentation](https://github.com/urfave/negroni) where it says:

> If you have a route group of routes that need specific middleware to be executed, you can simply create a new Negroni instance and use it as your route handler.

However, when I make requests and use the debugger, I see that `(*Negroni).ServeHTTP` is called multiple times. For example, if I request `GET /favicon.ico` then the `staticHandler` function is called correctly and calls `WriteHeader(200)`, but after that it then calls into the next `mux.Router` which calls `WriteHeader(404)` which prints out a warning in the terminal because the header was written twice (`http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls`)

If it's for a route that doesn't exist then the Gorilla default `NotFoundHandler` is invoked 3 times (one for each `mux.Router`).

How do I get Negroni to stop invoking other handlers after the request was completed?

...and if I have misconfigured my Negroni instance, why doesn't it perform checks during initialization to warn me about an invalid configuration?

My understanding is that `negroni.Use` and `UseFunc` are for setting-up middleware (which are all invoked for every request), while `UseHandler` is to set-up the terminal handler (only 1 is invoked for each request, or fallback to 404). If I understand the situation correctly then for some reason it's treating my terminal handlers as middlewares.

Comment: is here the full list of routes? do you have any routes like "/{category}"?

Comment: @vitr I can reproduce the issue with the code posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `UseHandler` documentation (https://godoc.org/github.com/urfave/negroni#Negroni.UseHandler)

> UseHandler adds a http.Handler onto the middleware stack. **Handlers are invoked in the order they are added to a Negroni.**

So it seems what you are seeing here is the expected behaviour.

You are basically creating different negroni instances and chaining them, so your final `negroniStack` is a middleware itself which will execute the other middlewares you added.

I believe what you want to do is create routes using an actual router, then add the appropriate middleware (using negroni) to each route.

If you look at the example you linked from the docs, that's what they are doing in that section (https://github.com/urfave/negroni#route-specific-middleware).

```
router.PathPrefix("/admin").Handler(negroni.New(
   Middleware1,
   Middleware2,
   negroni.Wrap(adminRoutes),
))
```

See that they are not nesting negroni instances but rather creating just one which is applied to the desired routes.

Comment: I'm not using `PathPrefix` or `Subrouter` though - so I'd have to repeat `negroni.New( mw1, mw2, negroni.Wrap( HandlerNameHere ) )` for every route (20+ of them). I don't like that design - it isn't very DRY. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @Dai: you'll definitely have to restructure how you are building this, one option for not repeating code would be to create a function that creates the negroni and wraps whatever handler you are creating, and call it like wrapWithCors(myHandler)... just an example

Comment: Yes, that would work - though it still doesn't feel right. It makes more sense to me to wrap a router (with all of its registered routes) in a middleware layer than it does to associate it with each route - but I can't see how because there's no way to "merge" `Router` objects unless they're in a hierarchy.

Comment: This worked in the end - though rather than calling `negroni.New( mw1, mw2, negroni.Wrap(ActualHandler))` inside the `router.Handler()` method, I instead use another function, but the principle is the same.